# Emit and on - NodeJS in separate emodule inside a function

Tags: node.js, events

I have simple module - `logger.js`:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events');
var emitter = new EventEmitter();

const log = (message) => {
   emitter.emit('logging');
    console.log('here')
}

module.exports.log= log;
```

which I am importing in another file:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const emitter = new EventEmitter();
emitter.on('logging', () => {
    console.log('Logging:')
});

const logger = require('./logger');
logger.log(90);
```

, I see `90` - the message, but I don't see `console.log('Logging:')`, why is that ?

It works, if I put all in one file, without wrapping `emit` in function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `EventEmitter` object you create is a new instance so events fired from the first one won't be triggered in the second. You need to use the same `EventEmitter` object.